# How to open WPF application from an other WPF both using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to us the demo code from [wpf chrometabs](https://github.com/sskodje/wpfchrometabs-mvvm) and in the other application I just added a button that calls the constructor of the demo:

```
private void FrontendDebug_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Demo.MainWindow mainWindow = new Demo.MainWindow();
   mainWindow.Show();
}
```

The problem is that it throws an exception at the `InitalizeComponent`:

[image: Exception]

I read somewhere that in MVVM, the `DataContext` should be set before calling `InitializeComponent()` but I don't know if that is the problem here or how to do it if it is.

Comment: Please show your XAML code. The error points out that you use a `{StaticResource Locator}` that cannot be resolved.

Comment: it is in the 17th line of this file https://github.com/sskodje/wpfchrometabs-mvvm/blob/master/Demo/CustomStyleExampleWindow.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you get points out, that you use a `StaticResource` markup extension to reference a resource with key `Locator` that is not found in this line:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=ViewModelMainWindow}"
```

The locator is defined in the application resources, so it is accessible in the whole application. Either you accidentially removed it or there is a typo in `App.xaml`. Make sure that it looks like this.

```
<Application x:Class="Demo.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <Application.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModel" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

> I am trying to us the demo code from wpf chrometabs and in the **other application** I just added a button that calls the constructor of the demo:

If you have **another** application that uses the demo project as library, the call below will only create an instance of the `MainWindow`. It will **not bootstrap** the application in the demo project.

```
Demo.MainWindow mainWindow = new Demo.MainWindow();
```

Consequently, the `App` object from the demo project is never created and its resources are not available. Even if it would be bootstrapped, the resources defined in `App.xaml` only apply to this application, nothing else.

Therefore, the `mainWindow` instance will try to find the resource in **your** application, not in the demo application. Since it is not defined there, you will get an exception. You could add the view model locator to your application's `App.xaml` resources, but keep in mind that is applies to all resources defined on the application level.

Comment: Thank you! The files are as in the git repo. I cloned it and it runs if i open it's solution. When I try to open it from the other WPF app button click only then i have this problem.

Comment: Sorry you were right. I was using 139f5ed8f7c2f5d107cd8f5913f221e89a967047 state before it was converted to .net core and the problem is present there.

Comment: Sorry again I checked everything. If I open it with the button from the other app only then I get the exception. If I open the .csproj in a separate VS window and run it it works.

Comment: Is it possible that since the ViewModelLocator is only available in the project in the solution and it should be accessible in the whole application? How could I do that?